# External table error - ORA-29913: error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEOPEN callout

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, database-administration

I am trying to use oracle external table feature to load flat file into database but encounter a error while execute SELECT statement on external table which i have created.
Below are the exact steps that  i am following --

```
/user2/cbusdev01/smp43/domains/columbus/tools>mkdir data_1
/user2/cbusdev01/smp43/domains/columbus/tools>chmod 777 data_1
```

create a file inside the data_1 folder add_len.csv
    Barbados_1000230,2461000230,2461000230,SSLN 00 0 00 138
    Barbados_1000229,2461000229,2461000229,SSLN 00 0 00 139
    Barbados_1000228,2461000228,2461000228,SSLN 00 0 03 14

login to sysdba --
    grant create any directory to cbusdev01cm;
    grant read, write on DIRECTORY data_1 to cbusdev01cm;

Now create a external table --

```
CREATE TABLE add_len_ext (
  country_code      VARCHAR2(20),
  sip               NUMBER,
  tn                NUMBER,
  len               VARCHAR2(30) 
)
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL (
  TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
  DEFAULT DIRECTORY data_1
  ACCESS PARAMETERS (
    RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
    BADFILE data_1:'bad.bad'
     LOGFILE data_1:'log.log'
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL
    (
      country_code      CHAR(50),
      sip               CHAR(50),
      tn                CHAR(50),
      len               CHAR(50)
    )
  )
  LOCATION (data_1:'add_len.csv')
)
PARALLEL 5
REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;

Table ADD_LEN_EXT created.
```

Then i fire the SELECT statement

```
select * from ADD_LEN_EXT;
```

And it gives me --

```
ORA-29913: error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEOPEN callout
ORA-29400: data cartridge error
error opening file /user2/cbusdev01/smp43/domains/columbus/tools/log.log
29913. 00000 -  "error in executing %s callout"
*Cause:    The execution of the specified callout caused an error.
*Action:   Examine the error messages take appropriate action.
```

I am not getting this error !!
I have granted all the permission to concerns but still the error is coming.

I am using --

```
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.3.0 - Production
"CORE 11.2.0.3.0 Production"
TNS for Linux: Version 11.2.0.3.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.3.0 - Production
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the `create directory` statement. Does it refer to `tools` or to `tools/data_1`?

The error message mentions OS directory `/user2/cbusdev01/smp43/domains/columbus/tools`, not your new `data_1` subdirectory.

Comment: Yes william that is one cause and another is that i need to create this file at DB server not here so when i did this the problem got solve !